# Web API Service. Is it possible to use https address via --urls parameter

Tags: .net, asp.net-web-api

I have implemented Web API Service (.NET 6) that is operating as windows service that is being launched (executable path) with parameter --urls=http://0.0.0.0:8444

[image: service]

Service works ok but now I want to switch it to https

I have successfully binded valid certificate to 8444 port via cmd:
netsh http add sslcert ipport=0.0.0.0:8444 appid=XXX certhash=ZZZ

I have changed *Path to executable* to --urls=https://0.0.0.0:8444 but since that service is refusing to start

How shall I modify --urls parameter and what shall I change inside Startup.cs ?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: _"service is refusing to start"_ - view the Event Log to find out why.

Answer (score 1):

First, you must update your URL to HTTPS, as you mentioned.

```
--urls=https://0.0.0.0:8444
```

You must use `UseHttpRedirection` before `UseRouting` on `Configure` in `Startup.cs` file.

```
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
```

You can also enable [hsts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security) in your app with the

```
app.UseHsts();
```

To customize the port use `AddHttpsRedirection` middleware on `ConfigureServices`.

```
services.AddHttpsRedirection(options =>
{
    options.HttpsPort = port;
    options.RedirectStatusCode = statusCode;
});
```

Comment: Thank you, @Emre. Finally I refused to configure services via --urls parameter and use *.json config nowadays. Hope your solution works great!